# Migrating from JUnit to TestNG in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, migration, testng

I found information about migrating from JUnit to TestNG in general ([here](http://testng.org/doc/migrating.html) for example) and about working in IntelliJ IDEA with JUnit and TestNG separately, but nothing about migrating from JUnit to TestNG in IntelliJ IDEA itself.

Can anyone describe the steps required to do this?

Comment: What do you mean? why would migrating from JUnit to TestNG be related to the IDE? in other words, why migrating from Junit to TestNG in eclipse would be different than in intelliJ?

Comment: @Hilikus I thought there might be something in the setting of the IDE or in the project settings that need to be changed. Are you saying that there's nothing that needs to be done?

Comment: there's a lot to be done *in the test code*, but in the IDE not, maybe just configure the new launchers, which is covered in any TestNG tutorial as it is not specific to migration but just running your TestNG tests in your IDE

Comment: I opened an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141175